# Assembly built by TFS executes differently from local assembly

Tags: wcf, deployment, dll, tfs

I have a WCF application that is built using a TFS build in Release.  This build succeeds and outputs to its _PublishedWebsites folder correctly.

I deploy this application and all services work apart from one method in one service.  Although strangely this method exists in another service which does work correctly.  All endpoints and bindings are correct in the config.

With this method not working if I then compile this application on my local machine in Release mode and copy the sole application DLL over the deployed DLL created using the TFS build the method starts to work.  If I then revert back to the TFS build DLL it stops working.

Is there any reason why the TFS build DLL would work differently to a local compiled DLL if they are both in Release mode?

Thank you

Comment: can u please paste the error that u receive.

Comment: Hey rauts.  My error is - "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://addressHere/service.svc/.  This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down)".  Although the binding this service uses is HTTP and is the same binding used for another service running the same method which works.  This is the error that occurs using the TFS build DLL. Replacing this with the local complied DLL (also in release) fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is SO obvious that this difference is somewhere in the deployed assembly, use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile both the TFS build and the Development system buid versions of the DLL. Then compare the sources of the operation that is not working for you.

Another possibility is that there is a difference in compilation settings on both systems. Maybe one is compiling for 64-bit and the other is 32-bit. Or maybe one is debug while the other is release. Or the are maybe even targetting different versions of the .NET framework!

Please report back what the difference is, I'm interested :-)

Comment: Hey kroonwijk.  Thanks alot for posting.  Firstly they are both compiled in Release for AnyCPU and both are targeting .Net 2.0 framework.  When using ILSpy the only assembly attribute that is different is on the TFS DLL and is [assembly: ComVisible(false)].  Could this make a difference?

Comment: So that means you are using different VS projects or settings to compile on TFS and on your local machine. Is that correct?

Comment: Also when comparing the methods in ILSpy there was a difference. My .cs file has the line Guid id = revisionInfo.PrimaryFileID; where revisionInfo is my object and PrimaryFileID is a GUID property.  The Local DLL has the line Guid id = revisionInfo.get_PrimaryFileID() and the TFS DLL has the line Guid id = revisionInfo.PrimaryFileID thus matching that of my .cs.  This could be it but i don't understand the difference.

Comment: The TFS build uses the same VS projects and solutions as I use locally.  Because of this I believe the same settings for compilation.

Comment: In response to my first comment [assembly: ComVisible(false)] is in my projects AssemblyInfo.cs file so thinking this may not be the issue and explains why it is not in the Local DLL assembly attributes?

Comment: But building locally, you also have this assemblyinfo.cs and should end up also there. If TFS and local build use the same solution and projects, the output should also be the same. Maybe the compiler used on your local machine and TFS build server is different? Are you OSes and .NET versions and 32/64 bit platform the same on TFS build server and your local machine?

Comment: Good points. The TFS server is 64 bit / windows 2008 R2 and has a 64 bit install of TFS server 2010.  This is the machine where the build controller is hosted.  The build server is 32 bit / windows 2003 R2 and this is where the build agents are hosted (also TFS 2010).  My local machine is 32 bit / windows 7 enterprise (VS 2010).  The .Net framework versions are the same across all platforms.  In my projects / solutions the build configurations compile for AnyCPU would it help targeting say x86 (32 bit) directly?

Comment: Just checked my CSC.exe versions and they are indeed different.  My build server has v8.0.50727.3083 and my local machine has a newer version v8.0.50727.4927.  These are the CSC.exe's that exist in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" folder on the respective machines.  This must be the issue?

Comment: Found a list of VS and CSC versions in this question also http://bit.ly/vyePu4.  Appears the my CSC is for Windows 7 and the build servers CSC is 3.5 SP1.